# How to sort varchar type column that contain both string and numeric values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has column name "BatchNo" and it contain both string and numeric values together. when i typed a select query i got following results.

[image]

i want to sort "BatchNo" column in following format

[image]

In my problem future batches may be have a,b,c .... letters with numeric values or only numeric values. how can i sort this column ? Hope you guys can help me to get some solution.

Comment: This is going to be difficult without regex capabilities. The letters should really be in a separate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you alter the schema of your table into?

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    ShipmentNo INT,
    ProjectCode VARCHAR(50),
    BatchNo INT,
    SubBatch INT,
    .....
)
```

in this way, it is to sort the valkues the way you want.

follow-up question, is `BatchNo` has only single character value from `A-Z`, eg

```
11a
11b
```

and not

```
11aa
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT   *
FROM     tableName
ORDER BY CASE ISNUMERIC(batchNo)
            WHEN 1 THEN batchNo
            ELSE CAST(LEFT(batchNo, LEN(batchNo) - 1) AS INT)
         END
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59a87/5)

Comment: If BatchNo and SubBatch both are going to be INT. how can i put a,b,c values ?

Comment: you can also change subbatch into `VARCHAR`. anyway, i have another solution based on your question, [see this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59a87/5) (*only works if the the value has max length of 1 letter*)

Comment: There is a another problem. if i use this query like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2206e/2/0
i got top value as 1b. how to resolve this ?

Comment: @sha thank yu for the follow-up question, you can add `batchNo` on order by clause. [Click this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2206e/5)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY 
CAST(LEFT(BatchNo, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', BatchNo + 'Z')-1) AS INT),
BatchNo
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31ecd/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(BatchNo, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', BatchNo + 'A')-1) AS INT)
```

Query works for a string which starts with numeric values only.